# Understanding `respond_with` in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with `before_create` and `before_update` callbacks that can `return false`. The model is NOT saved when the callbacks fail (as expected), however my controller redirects to the index path on the model not being created (as opposed to rendering the new template). My code is:

```
class Person
  before_create :reversify
  before_update :reversify

  def reversify
    return false if self.name.blank?
    self.name = self.name.reverse
  end
end

class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html

  def new
    @person = Person.new
    respond_with(@person)
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.create(params[:person])
    respond_with(@person)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`respond_with` uses the presence / absence of `@person.errors` to determine the appropriate RESTful response.

I'm going to theorise that because you're relying on using failing callbacks to prevent saving invalid objects, ActiveRecord isn't populating `@person.errors`, which results in `ActionController::Responder` determining that the save was successful.

I suggest re-writing your Person class to use a validation:

```
class Person
  before_save :reversify

  validates :name, :presence => true

  def reversify     
    self.name.reverse!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Sorry I failed to specify the example above was greatly simplified (I'm actually integrating with a payment processing service), but I did end up dropping the use of `responds_with` and reverted to a `respond_to` block. Cheers.